# How can i stop the Windows service in C++ ? (MFC Dialog app)

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I would like to stop sixteen windows services by pressing a button. But it´s do not work. I'm desperate.

```
void CTestMFCAppDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    BOOL cResult = FALSE;

#define MAX_VALUE 17

    for (int numberOfService = 0; numberOfService < MAX_VALUE; numberOfService++) {

        CString StringServiceName;
        StringServiceName.Format(_T("Sense Counter %d"), numberOfService);

        SC_HANDLE hndSvcMan = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);

        if (hndSvcMan != NULL)
        {
            SC_HANDLE hndService = OpenService(hndSvcMan, StringServiceName, SERVICE_STOP);
        }
        else
            cResult = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably should check the return value from `OpenService()` to see if the returned handle is NULL if it is call GetLastError() to understand the problem.

Comment: Good chances are of access denied errors

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You find full code here http://www.naughter.com/serv.html

Answer (score 1):

All your code is doing is *opening handles* to the services (and leaking them), but it is not attempting to *actually stop* the services.

If `OpenService()` is successful in opening a service, call [`ControlService(SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-controlservice) to request the service to stop. You can monitor the service's status with [`QueryServiceStatus()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-queryservicestatus) to wait for the stop operation to finish. And then close the service handle with [`CloseServiceHandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-closeservicehandle).

MSDN even provides an example of this exact process:

[Stopping a Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/stopping-a-service)

```cpp
//
// Purpose: 
//   Stops the service.
//
// Parameters:
//   None
// 
// Return value:
//   None
//
VOID __stdcall DoStopSvc()
{
    SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS ssp;
    DWORD dwStartTime = GetTickCount();
    DWORD dwBytesNeeded;
    DWORD dwTimeout = 30000; // 30-second time-out
    DWORD dwWaitTime;

    // Get a handle to the SCM database. 
 
    schSCManager = OpenSCManager( 
        NULL,                    // local computer
        NULL,                    // ServicesActive database 
        SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);  // full access rights 
 
    if (NULL == schSCManager) 
    {
        printf("OpenSCManager failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Get a handle to the service.

    schService = OpenService( 
        schSCManager,         // SCM database 
        szSvcName,            // name of service 
        SERVICE_STOP | 
        SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS | 
        SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS);  
 
    if (schService == NULL)
    { 
        printf("OpenService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError()); 
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return;
    }    

    // Make sure the service is not already stopped.

    if ( !QueryServiceStatusEx( 
            schService, 
            SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,
            (LPBYTE)&ssp, 
            sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS),
            &dwBytesNeeded ) )
    {
        printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError()); 
        goto stop_cleanup;
    }

    if ( ssp.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOPPED )
    {
        printf("Service is already stopped.\n");
        goto stop_cleanup;
    }

    // If a stop is pending, wait for it.

    while ( ssp.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOP_PENDING ) 
    {
        printf("Service stop pending...\n");

        // Do not wait longer than the wait hint. A good interval is 
        // one-tenth of the wait hint but not less than 1 second  
        // and not more than 10 seconds. 
 
        dwWaitTime = ssp.dwWaitHint / 10;

        if( dwWaitTime < 1000 )
            dwWaitTime = 1000;
        else if ( dwWaitTime > 10000 )
            dwWaitTime = 10000;

        Sleep( dwWaitTime );

        if ( !QueryServiceStatusEx( 
                 schService, 
                 SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,
                 (LPBYTE)&ssp, 
                 sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS),
                 &dwBytesNeeded ) )
        {
            printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError()); 
            goto stop_cleanup;
        }

        if ( ssp.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOPPED )
        {
            printf("Service stopped successfully.\n");
            goto stop_cleanup;
        }

        if ( GetTickCount() - dwStartTime > dwTimeout )
        {
            printf("Service stop timed out.\n");
            goto stop_cleanup;
        }
    }

    // If the service is running, dependencies must be stopped first.

    StopDependentServices();

    // Send a stop code to the service.

    if ( !ControlService( 
            schService, 
            SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, 
            (LPSERVICE_STATUS) &ssp ) )
    {
        printf( "ControlService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError() );
        goto stop_cleanup;
    }

    // Wait for the service to stop.

    while ( ssp.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOPPED ) 
    {
        Sleep( ssp.dwWaitHint );
        if ( !QueryServiceStatusEx( 
                schService, 
                SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,
                (LPBYTE)&ssp, 
                sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS),
                &dwBytesNeeded ) )
        {
            printf( "QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError() );
            goto stop_cleanup;
        }

        if ( ssp.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOPPED )
            break;

        if ( GetTickCount() - dwStartTime > dwTimeout )
        {
            printf( "Wait timed out\n" );
            goto stop_cleanup;
        }
    }
    printf("Service stopped successfully\n");

stop_cleanup:
    CloseServiceHandle(schService); 
    CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
}

BOOL __stdcall StopDependentServices()
{
    DWORD i;
    DWORD dwBytesNeeded;
    DWORD dwCount;

    LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS   lpDependencies = NULL;
    ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS     ess;
    SC_HANDLE               hDepService;
    SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS  ssp;

    DWORD dwStartTime = GetTickCount();
    DWORD dwTimeout = 30000; // 30-second time-out

    // Pass a zero-length buffer to get the required buffer size.
    if ( EnumDependentServices( schService, SERVICE_ACTIVE, 
         lpDependencies, 0, &dwBytesNeeded, &dwCount ) ) 
    {
         // If the Enum call succeeds, then there are no dependent
         // services, so do nothing.
         return TRUE;
    } 
    else 
    {
        if ( GetLastError() != ERROR_MORE_DATA )
            return FALSE; // Unexpected error

        // Allocate a buffer for the dependencies.
        lpDependencies = (LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS) HeapAlloc( 
            GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwBytesNeeded );
  
        if ( !lpDependencies )
            return FALSE;

        __try {
            // Enumerate the dependencies.
            if ( !EnumDependentServices( schService, SERVICE_ACTIVE, 
                lpDependencies, dwBytesNeeded, &dwBytesNeeded,
                &dwCount ) )
            return FALSE;

            for ( i = 0; i < dwCount; i++ ) 
            {
                ess = *(lpDependencies + i);
                // Open the service.
                hDepService = OpenService( schSCManager, 
                   ess.lpServiceName, 
                   SERVICE_STOP | SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS );

                if ( !hDepService )
                   return FALSE;

                __try {
                    // Send a stop code.
                    if ( !ControlService( hDepService, 
                            SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP,
                            (LPSERVICE_STATUS) &ssp ) )
                    return FALSE;

                    // Wait for the service to stop.
                    while ( ssp.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOPPED ) 
                    {
                        Sleep( ssp.dwWaitHint );
                        if ( !QueryServiceStatusEx( 
                                hDepService, 
                                SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,
                                (LPBYTE)&ssp, 
                                sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS),
                                &dwBytesNeeded ) )
                        return FALSE;

                        if ( ssp.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOPPED )
                            break;

                        if ( GetTickCount() - dwStartTime > dwTimeout )
                            return FALSE;
                    }
                } 
                __finally 
                {
                    // Always release the service handle.
                    CloseServiceHandle( hDepService );
                }
            }
        } 
        __finally 
        {
            // Always free the enumeration buffer.
            HeapFree( GetProcessHeap(), 0, lpDependencies );
        }
    } 
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Adding a `Sleep` in `Onclick` event is the perfect way to produce a **freeze**, and depending on machine resources it can reproduce the famous error "**the window is not responding...**" because it will block **ALL messages pump**

Comment: @Landstalker Obviously, it is just an example. Since the stop request and the status wait are separate operations, you can separate out the wait logic to run asynchronously, for instance by using a timer or a thread.